# JS change JSON single quotes to double

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a JSON coming from back end to front, that uses single quotes everywhere (I can't change the generator, because Magento 2 widget I use is braking if double quotes are passed). It looks like this:

```
{ 'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why shouldn't I?'}
```

I need to change the single quotes to double, without actually touching the apostrophes in the middle. I think the best way to do this would be to use a regular expression to match all JSON-related single quotes and replace them to double, without touching the apostrophes inside.

There are plenty of questions like this one on SO, but I haven't been able to find a solution that actually works for me for the last 1.5 hours. The closest solution so far was this:

```
goodJson = brokenJson.replace(/(?<=[{,:] )'|'(?=[:,]| })/g, '"');
```

It should match all single quotes that are either preceded by `{`, `,`,  , and `:`, or followed by those characters. However, in my output I get this:

```
{ "mood": "happy", "reason": "why'd not'}
```

So, the final quote is not being replaced despite standing next to the closing curly brace.

Can you tell me why doesn't it work, and what would be the best way to achieve desired outcome?

Comment: It's not JSON. It's broken. It's ambiguous. What if the string was `why shouldn': 'I'`? There's no way to *know* what the correct JSON was supposed to be. The solution is to not send broken JSON.

Comment: `I have a JSON coming from back end to front` techncially, you don't, since JSON uses `"` not `'` - anyway ... remove the space here `| }` - though, that still won't account for all possible inputs of course (`| ?}` also works)

Comment: "because Magento 2 widget I use is braking" — Sounds like the widget needs fixing. It might be vulnerable to XSS so that's doubly important that you check it.

Comment: @DanyloHerasymov - I would hardly call that a "fix" (which is why it's not posted as an answer) ... it's a temporary band-aid until you fix the "source" to actually send JSON :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your character string does not represent a JSON format, your regex was not far from the correct result:

```js
const goodJson = brokenJson => brokenJson.replace(/(?<=[{,: ])'|'(?=[:, }])/g, '"');

console.log(goodJson("{ 'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why'd not' }")); // { "mood": "happy", "reason": "why'd not" }
console.log(goodJson("{'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why'd not'}")); // {"mood": "happy", "reason": "why'd not"}
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this is not JSON, best to have this fixed upstream. If you want to fix broken JSON to a flaky JSON, and the value is always a string, you can try this:

```js
function brokenToFlakyJson(str) {
 return str.replace(/'(\w+)' *: *'(.*?)'(?=[,| *\}])/g, '"$1": "$2"');
}

[
  "{ 'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why shouldn't I?'}",
  "{ 'mood': 'happy 'cat'', 'reason': 'why shouldn't I?'}",
  "{ 'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why shouldn't', 'I?'}",
].forEach(str => {
  console.log('broken: ' + str + '\n flaky: ' + brokenToFlakyJson(str));
})
```

Output:

```
broken: { 'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why shouldn't I?'}
 flaky: { "mood": "happy", "reason": "why shouldn't I?"}
broken: { 'mood': 'happy 'cat'', 'reason': 'why shouldn't I?'}
 flaky: { "mood": "happy 'cat'", "reason": "why shouldn't I?"}
broken: { 'mood': 'happy', 'reason': 'why shouldn't', 'I?'}
 flaky: { "mood": "happy", "reason": "why shouldn't", 'I?'}
```

As you can see from the output, the 3rd string is not handled properly. We can add another safeguard, but that one will break too, etc.

Explanation of regex:

- `'(\w+)'` -- expect key enclosed in single quotes
- `*: *` -- expect colon separator with optional spaces
- `'(.*?)'` -- expect value enclosed in single quotes, non-greedy scan
- `(?=[,| *\}])` -- positive lookahead, expecting a comma or end of object